# How to take random samples from different lists and combine them into a new list?

Tags: python, random

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [7, 8, 9, 0]
```

My goal is to randomly take 3 values from each list and combine them into one new list.

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```

With `random.sample` I can pick up values from one list at a time.

```
x = random.sample(a, 3)
y = random.sample(b, 3)
```

I could combine the results in several steps but I wonder if there is a cleaner version of this.

Comment: What is the version that you attempted and why do you think it could be improved upon?

Comment: @navneethc It's in their question: OP's current solution is to create two lists using `random.sample()` then to use list concatenation to create a resultant list.

Comment: you can combine those lists with `x + y` or `x.extend(y)`.  If you have very long lists, numpy will be more performant but otherwise similar

Comment: I thought there would be a solution ( or a module ) like "pick three from that list and three from that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a one-liner...

```
import random
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  # List a
b = [7, 8, 9, 0]  # List b
# If you want a one-liner, this should do
x, y = zip(*random.sample(list(zip(a, b)), 3))
c = list(x + y)  # Combining the two sample sets
print(c)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the `list.extend()` method:

```py
import random

lists = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 0]
]
samples = []
for i in lists:
    samples.extend(random.sample(i, 3))
```

Comment: The lists aren't nested. But thank you nevertheless.

Comment: @oOinsaneOo I just nested the two lists into one larger list to allow for iteration. Alternatively, you could do something like `lists = [a, b]`.

Comment: Ok. I thought there would be a solution to pick up the values in a one-liner. "Pick three from that location and three from another". But it seems that this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Ok. I thought there would be a solution to pick up the values in a one-liner.

If you really **need** a one-liner...

```
[thing for x in (random.sample(q,3) for q in (a,b)) for thing in x]
```

---

Some prep then the one liner - please no groans.

```
>>> from functools import reduce,partial
>>> from operator import add
>>> reduce(add,map(partial(random.sample,**{'k':3}), (a,b)))
[2, 3, 6, 7, 0, 8]
>>>    # or
>>> reduce(add,map(lambda w: random.sample(w,3), (a,b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution that is acceptable for me:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [7, 8, 9, 0]

c_first = [random.sample(a, 3), random.sample(b, 3)]

# Output [[1, 3, 5], [8, 7, 9]]

c_second = [item for sublist in c_first for item in sublist]

print(c_second)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 8, 7, 9]
```